# How to create a dictionary with nested dictionary with multiple key value pairs using a loop?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Hello I am building a web scraping program and I am struggling with creating a dictionary in a certain way I would like, and I haven't found anything too similar with what I am trying to do after hours of searching.

These are the lists I would like to combine into a dictionary.

```
number = [1,2]
attributes = [' 75 cm', ' 3 cm', ' 125 cm', ' 7.30 kg', ' 1', ' 27 cm', ' 9 cm', ' 71 cm', ' 21.70 kg', ' 1']
measure_without_duplicates = ['Width:', 'Height:', 'Length:', 'Weight:', 'Package(s):']
```

This is the specific way I would like to create the dictionary:

```
dictionary = {1 : {'Width:':' 75 cm', 'Height:':' 3 cm', 'Length:':' 125 cm', 'Weight:': '7.30 kg', 'Package(s):':' 1'}, 2: {'Width:':' 27 cm', 'Height:':' 9 cm', 'Length:':' 71 cm', 'Weight:': '21.70 kg', 'Package(s):':' 1'}
```

It will need to repeat the items within measure_without_duplicates as many times needed as a key for the values of attributes depending on how many numbers there are.

There are 2 in this instance, so it needs to iterate twice, because there are two packages needed for a single product. These measures need to correlate to the attributes array, but these will not repeat, instead carry over to the next package.

I cannot splice the list with the attributes because the list can have a minimum of 5 items, depending on how many packages will be needed. Like I said, this is a web scraping project so I need to be able to have flexible code.

The reason I have created a variable called measure_without_duplicates is because I have another array in my program which is called measures and looks like this:

```
measure = ['Width:', 'Height:', 'Length:', 'Weight:', 'Package(s):', 'Width:', 'Height:', 'Length:', 'Weight:', 'Package(s):']
```

And I wrote a little code which removes any duplication from the list.

I tried to write some code for this problem, but it doesn't work without an error occuring. I've tried other things but it would be hard for me to get the previous attempts so I'll just put down the latest code I have:

```
for key in range(len(number)):
    for iteration in range(len(measure_without_duplicates)):
        dictionary[str(key+1)][measure_without_duplicates[iteration]]=attributes[iteration]
print(dictionary)
```

and I get an error:

```
    dictionary[str(key+1)][measure_without_duplicates[iteration]]=attributes[iteration]
KeyError: '1'
```

I really appreciate any help, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Using `iter` and `zip`. `iter` will make sure you only iterate over it how many you consume and here it's allowing us to pick back up on that iterable where we left off:

```
number = [1,2]
attributes = [' 75 cm', ' 3 cm', ' 125 cm', ' 7.30 kg', ' 1', ' 27 cm', ' 9 cm', ' 71 cm', ' 21.70 kg', ' 1']
measure_without_duplicates = ['Width:', 'Height:', 'Length:', 'Weight:', 'Package(s):']

attrs = iter(attributes)

print({i: dict(zip(measure_without_duplicates, attrs)) for i in number})
```

---

```
{1: {'Width:': ' 75 cm', 'Height:': ' 3 cm', 'Length:': ' 125 cm', 'Weight:': ' 7.30 kg', 'Package(s):': ' 1'}, 2: {'Width:': ' 27 cm', 'Height:': ' 9 cm', 'Length:': ' 71 cm', 'Weight:': ' 21.70 kg', 'Package(s):': ' 1'}}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I needed!